# Mac laptop security on insecure wifi connections

Tags: wifi, macos

I'm going every year at big IT conferences (3k->4k people). Everyone is connected to the internet with wifi on laptops. This wifi is open, everyone can read the traffic and analyse it... The risk is nearly the same on wifi in hotel, hotspot etc.. except you have a concentration of interesting informations and hacking competencies at the same place...

I use those precautions on my mac :

1. use SSL everywhere
2. avoid to sent sensitive data even on encrypted link
3. encrypt data on disk
4. take the laptop with you everywhere
5. antivirus
6. update Mac OS X to the last version

Is there other security measure to take on mac ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the threat model?  With the exception of particularly hostile environments (DEF CON, for example), I just connect to a VPN and move on with things.  I believe I have my laptop hardened adequately to protect against general malware, theft, etc., by:

1. Don't run network exposed services.
2. Firewall in case I screw up #1.
3. Patched.
4. VPN.
5. Full Disk Encryption.  (This is the theft bit.)

If you're worried about [Evil Maid Attacks](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html) or other targeted attacks, you'll need to take more precautions, but if it's just general malware/bored script kiddies you're concerned with, then patch, run a VPN, and enjoy the conference.

Comment: can be also defcon ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run a Linux virtual machine on an attached 64 GB USB and do not use your hard drive until you are back home on your own network.

Set up certificates for the VPN before going.

SSL/TLS is spoofable using various common techniques exposing you to a MITM attack

Be prepared that the SSID that you connect to may have already been evil twinned and thus already MITMed.

Consider not using WIFI and use a 4G hot spot alternative

Comment: I think that handwaving around spoofing SSL/TLS as "various common techniques" is disingenuous at best.  It's not _that_ easy.

Comment: It's one of the reasons that certificate pinning in Google Chrome is a requirement. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning